# Is there a way to get a pair having both the lower_bound and upper_bound in a sorted array?

Tags: c++

If I have a `std::vector` having elements `{1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3}`

Is there a way to get a pair containing the `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` for value = 2 ?

Instead of me calling `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` separately.

Comment: You are looking for `equal_range`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`std::equal_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range).

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, literally: [`std::equal_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range)